# Aside ANOVA [Repeated Measure], is there a more efficient approach to repeated measure longitudinal data?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, repeated-measures, panel-data

I came across a discussion thread on ResearchGate's where one researcher mentioned that repeated measure ANOVA is an outdated approach to longitudinal and intensive longitudinal data.
It is known that drawbacks include order of treatments, often violated assumption of sphericity and according Kim of Analysis factor,

> "One of the biggest problems with traditional repeated measures ANOVA is missing data on the response variable... problem is that repeated measures ANOVA treats each measurement as a separate variable. "  [Analysis Factor Blog](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/when-repeated-measures-anova-not-work-for-repeated-measures-data/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjwyKmDg4HvAhU_wQIHHaD-AfgQFnoECAYQAg&usg=AOvVaw26M2SHwab-7Ouxaeem_Eh2)

Is there a comparable or alternative best approach? (And please, I really need your insight and experience on this subject matter). Give reference, where your approach was explored with examples. Thanks.

Comment: See https://fharrell.com/post/re .  Repeated measures ANOVA is indeed obsolete.

Comment: I agree with you, @FrankHarrell. Apart from mixed effect models what other approaches are currently being used?

Comment: See the above link.   Primarily Markov models (which apply extremely widely) and generalized least squares (for continuous Y, Gaussian residuals).  GEE is also an option, with cluster sandwich covariance correction, but is not as robust.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, Oh, that is great! GEE , with advantage of consistent parameters estimates, is sure another option. Developed by (Liang and Zeger, 1986) to [produce regression estimates when analyzing repeated measures with non-normal response variables](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/repeated-measures-analysis ... )

Comment: GEE is a large sample procedure.  Most of us don't have large enough samples where asymptotics can be trusted.

Comment: Thanks Prof @FrankHarrell, I will really appreciate an answer at the answer section for others benefit and perhabs encouragement to contribute (filling any gaps in our understanding and modeling longitudinal/panel data of today's types)